# Change over time / absolute numbers

Tags: r

I have a knot in my head trying to find good search terms for my problem. I am sure this has a very simple solution.

I have data that looks like this:

```
f = data.frame(
  date = c(
    as.POSIXct('2012-01-01'),
    as.POSIXct('2012-02-01'),
    as.POSIXct('2012-03-01')
  ),
  val = c(
    22,
    45,
    67
  )
)

> f
        date val
1 2012-01-01  22
2 2012-02-01  45
3 2012-03-01  67
```

What I would like to find is the absolute change in "val" from one date to the other ("val" is taken at each first day of a month). So my end result should look like this

```
> new_f
        date val change
1 2012-01-01  22     NA
2 2012-02-01  45     23  #(45-22)
3 2012-03-01  67     22  #(67-45)
```

How can I calculate those change values?

Comment: Try `c(NA, diff(f$val))`

Comment: `f$change <- c(NA,diff(f$val))` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can also use the `lag` function instead of `diff`. This has the advantage that it already includes the `NA`.

```
require(dplyr)
f %>% mutate(change = val-lag(val))
##         date val change
## 1 2012-01-01  22     NA
## 2 2012-02-01  45     23
## 3 2012-03-01  67     22
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `diff` for that purpose:

```
f$change <- c(NA, diff(f$val))
f
##         date val change
## 1 2012-01-01  22     NA
## 2 2012-02-01  45     23
## 3 2012-03-01  67     22
```

Since `diff` shortens the input vector by 1, you can concatenate it with NA at the beginning using `c()`

Comment: I wonder if its worth adding `library(data.table) ; setDT(f)[, change := c(NA, val[-1] - val[-.N])]` and 
`library(dplyr) ; f %>% mutate(change = c(NA, val[-1] - val[-n()]))` for fun

Comment: I ended up using this approach, but the dplyr one seems also very good. And then shadow has less reputation, so I feel I should accept his answer instead. No offense meant!

Comment: @til_b, no offense taken. See [this post on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) regarding how and which answer to accept. I don't mind if you accept shadow's answer (it's good) but you shouldn't accept an answer because someone has lower rep than someone else. You can always upvote several answers if you like them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure your dates are unique and already ordered:

```
f$change = c(NA, tail(f$val,-1)-head(f$val,-1))
```